# How do I use single quotes in a MySQL select in bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash, sh

I have a query

```
Select id, contact_name from Profile where TRIM(IFNULL(contact_name,'')) <> ''
```

and I am trying to pass it into a Bash script.

```
mysql --user abc -psomePass MyData -e "SELECT `id`,`contact_name` from `Profile` where TRIM(IFNULL(`contact_name`,'') <> ''" | while read term_id; do
done
```

but it doesn't like the singe quotes `''`.  How do I format this in the script?

I have tried

```
TRIM(IFNULL(`contact_name`,\'\') <> \'\'"
```

and

```
TRIM(IFNULL(`contact_name`,\") <> \""
```

and

```
TRIM(IFNULL(`contact_name`,"''") <> "''""
```

I am out of ideas.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes if you're wrapping the whole thing in double quotes.

Comment: I don't think the problem are the single quotes, but the backticks are interpreted as command substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't like the single quotes.

Bash on my machine is fine with single quotes:

```
 $ echo "SELECT id,contact_name from Profile where TRIM(IFNULL(contact_name,'') <> ''"
 SELECT id,contact_name from Profile where TRIM(IFNULL(contact_name,'') <> ''
 $
```

Comment: The question had backticks that were hard to see because of formatting, and I think they cause the problem.

Comment: I figured out my own answer.  mysql -u abc -pSomePass MyData -s -e "SELECT id,contact_name from Profile where contact_name <> ''" | while read -a Result; do  I then looped though the Result array id=Result[0]  name = result[1] etc..